# Hudson and maven-release-plugin

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, hudson, maven-release-plugin

I'm using Hudson with the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/).

As you may know, the maven-release-plugin builds project in 2 steps: `release:prepare`, then `release:perform`.

How should I configure Hudson to execute `release:rollback` in case `release:perform` failed?

Comment: Why would you want to do a release through Hudson?  Do you want to release each build?

Comment: @Raghuram He might be choosing which build to release through parameters.

Answer (score 9):

The standard way of performing release with Hudson/Jenkins is the [Jenkins M2 release plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin). It wraps the maven release plugin and automates its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't.  Turn off update (do a clean checkout each time).  FWIW, in my experience release:rollback isn't terribly reliable anyways.

Comment: A clean checkout won't help if the previous rollout step broke *after* it checked the pom with the new version number into the VCN.

Comment: Hmm - what step broke?  Why did it fail?

Comment: I much prefer to delegate the troubleshooting of these problems, so I can't give you specifics ;-) I know it happened to us a few times. It was a highly customized Maven build, however, so some of the additional plugins might have messed it up, 'though.

Comment: I've been using Maven for ~4 years now, and I've never had the release plugin break during perform like that.  There are a number of things you can do to customize the build that might seem like a good idea but are actually a Bad Thing(tm).  :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is absolutely needed, than you should be able to do a "Invoke top-level Maven targets" build step where you will invoke the release:prepare and release:perform and catch on the result of this build through a "Execute system groovy script" build step.
Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557659/using-maven-release-plugin-autoversionsubmodules-to-increment-major-version/17699592#17699592) how to check pom.xml for versions (it might give you an idea if the perform failed or not).