# Using maven release plugin autoVersionSubmodules to increment Major version

Tags: hudson, maven-release-plugin

I'm using the maven release plugin on hudson with autoVersionSubmodules set to true to automatically increment the development version in the poms.

I'm wondering if there is a way to make the plugin increment the major version rather than minor version.

Currently when I'm at version 1.1.0-snapshot the next version is set to 1.1.1-snapshot but ideally I would like it to change to 1.2.0-snapshot.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) prompts you for the values of the release version to tag and also for the next development version.  You can define these to avoid prompting; usually you would set them at the command line with something like `mvn -DreleaseVersion=1.1.0 -DdevelopmentVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`.

However, if you are not getting prompted to select the version, then something is choosing for you.  If you are using the M2 Release Plugin for Hudson then I think it has options to select the version for you, but you should probably find a way to configure them explicitly.  More details about your particular setup would help.

Comment: Thanks Zac for your answer. I don't want it to prompt for the version but also I don't want to need to go and change the releaseVersion and developmentVersion every time. I just want to see if there is a way to automatically increase the version. Using -DautoVesrionSubmodules increases the minor version but I need to increase the major version. I want to go from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0

Comment: @Arya actually `-DautoVersionSubmodules` does not automatically pick the version for you.  It only makes sure that the version that is specified is applied to all modules (otherwise you are prompted for each).  I repeat, "something is choosing for you".  If it is maven, I don't think it is the release plugin.  I suspect there is something in your Hudson configuration to do it.

Answer (score 4):

> ...if there is a way to make the plugin increment the major version
>   rather than minor version.
>
> Currently when I'm at version 1.1.0-snapshot the next version is set
>   to 1.1.1-snapshot but ideally I would like it to change to
>   1.2.0-snapshot.

What you are describing here is that maven-release-plugin is incrementing your fix version and you want the minor version incremented. Where version `x.y.z` means `[majorVersion].[minorVersion].[fixVersion]`.

The way I solved this is in the following manner:

1. Create the groovy script that will pick the version from your `pom.xml` increment it in the manner you are explaining and set the `developmentVersion` and `releaseVersion` as Hudson string parameters.
2. Create a job on Hudson
3. Place the Groovy script in your job's workspace
4. On the job set a "Execute system groovy script" build step - provide the path to the Groovy script
5. On the job set a "Invoke top-level Maven targets" build step and invoke the maven release command with the `developmentVersion` and `releaseVersion` properties.

Step 1:

```java
import hudson.model.*  

createReleaseAndDevelopmentVersions ();  

def createReleaseAndDevelopmentVersions () {  
    def POM_LOCATION = build.parent.builds[0].properties.get("envVars")['WORKSPACE'] + "/pom.xml";  
    def SNAPSHOT_PART = "-SNAPSHOT";  
    def projectVersion = findOutCurrentVersion(POM_LOCATION);  
    def versionParts = projectVersion.tokenize('.');  
    def mayorVersionPart = versionParts[0];  
    def minorVersionPart = versionParts[1];  
    def fixVersionPart = versionParts[2];  
    def snapshotPartIndex = fixVersionPart.indexOf(SNAPSHOT_PART);  
    boolean hasSnapshotPart = snapshotPartIndex != -1;  
    if (hasSnapshotPart) {  
        fixVersionPart = fixVersionPart.substring(0, snapshotPartIndex);  
    }  
    int minorVersion = minorVersionPart.toInteger();  
    int fixVersion = fixVersionPart.toInteger();  
    def newFixVersion = 0;  
    def newMinorRelVersion;  
    def newMinorDevVersion;  
    if (hasSnapshotPart) {  
        newMinorRelVersion = minorVersion;  
        newMinorDevVersion = minorVersion + 1;  
    } else {  
        //TODO: either throw an exception here or change the newMinorRelVersion newMinorDevVersion appropriately to suite your use-cases: 
            //throw new IllegalArgumentException("The pom at location " + POM_LOCATION + " contains the version " + projectVersion + " which is not a snapshot version (missing " + SNAPSHOT_PART + "). This is a released version and nothing should happen to it!");  
    }  
    def releaseVersion = mayorVersionPart  + "." + newMinorRelVersion + "." + newFixVersion;  
    def developmentVersion = mayorVersionPart  + "." + newMinorDevVersion + "." + newFixVersion + SNAPSHOT_PART;  
    createJenkinsVariablesAndAddToCurrentJob(releaseVersion, developmentVersion);  
}  

def findOutCurrentVersion (POM_LOCATION) {  
    def thr = Thread.currentThread()  
    def build = thr?.executable  
    def projectVersionParam = "projectVersion"  
    def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver  
    def projectVersionParamValue = resolver.resolve(projectVersionParam)  
    return projectVersionParamValue  
}  
def createJenkinsVariablesAndAddToCurrentJob (releaseVersion, developmentVersion) {  
    def pa = new ParametersAction([  
        new StringParameterValue("releaseVersion", releaseVersion), new StringParameterValue("developmentVersion", developmentVersion)  
    ])  
    Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa)  
}
```

Step 5 (the maven command):

```
clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=${releaseVersion} -DdevelopmentVersion=${developmentVersion}
```

Cheers,
Despot