# Maven release: next development version in batch mode

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have configured a Jenkins job to release my maven project automatically. This is done by using the following: `mvn --batch-mode clean release:prepare release:perform`
In batch mode the release version and the development version will be determined automatically. This is exactly what I want.

The problem is that I want to increase the 2nd number of the version instead of the 3rd one. So when I release version 1.2.0, the next development version must be 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT. Not 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT.
Adding a commandline parameter is not an option, because that forces me to constantly edit the build job.

Any suggestions on how to change the algorithm used to determine the next development version?

Comment: Some objections against using **1.2-SNAPSHOT** instead of **1.2.0-SNAPSHOT**.

Comment: Why don't you use jenkins m2 release plugin ? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin

Comment: We might want to use the 3rd digit in the future for bug releases, but 2 digits will suffice for now. I didn't even know about the release plugin. Looks pretty useful, but doesn't seem to fix the problem regarding version increment on non-default version patterns. It does help selecting the right version though.

Comment: In case you have a bug you need to manually define the version but only for those cases. In the usual case you don't need to.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is a kinda old post but I didn't find an answer I really liked anywhere online and I was able to come up with something that might work well for others...

I wanted to increment the minorVersion as the OP states, and I was able to do so by using a combination of the build helper plugin (to parse the version) and the release plugin, in my project POM.  Note the "initialize" phase referenced in the POM and the maven run property...

Here's the excerpt from the POM, we use the build helper plugin to parse the version which we can reference in the release plugin...

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.build.helper.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>parse-versions-for-release</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>parse-version</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyPrefix>parsedVersion</propertyPrefix>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.release.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                    <developmentVersion>${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT</developmentVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Now we can just run a pretty normal release, but adding in the "initialize" phase to trigger the version parsing (and ensure it occurs prior to looking for the parsed versions)...

```
mvn initialize release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

Comment: When I try this solution the development version is set to the literal string `${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT`. That is, the properties for major and next minor versions are not resolved. Does anyone know why, and how I can solve that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `build-helper-maven-plugin`. Just add following to pom.xml:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.build.helper.plugin.version}</version>
    </plugin>
```

and change command to

```sh
mvn --batch-mode clean build-helper:parse-version release:prepare release:perform -DdevelopmentVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT
```

(please note that depending on environment you run this command in, you might need to escape `$` with `\`: `\$`)

Answer (score 2):

There is a parameter `projectVersionPolicyId` provided in the `release:prepare` mojo: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#projectVersionPolicyId

There might not be built-in version policy to satisfy your needs, but you can develop your own version policy by implementing the interface [VersionPolicy](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/shared/release/policy/version/VersionPolicy.html). You can see [maven-release-yearly-policy](https://github.com/ncredinburgh/maven-release-yearly-policy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ncredinburgh/maven/release/policy/YearlyVersionPolicy.java) as a reference, which provided a version policy using year in the version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a commandline parameter without editing the job if you use a parameterized build in Jenkins.  Check the "this build is parameterized" option in the job configuration page.

This won't let Jenkins perform releases entirely on its own (which is good; we don't want the robots to take our jobs!) -- when you manually kick off a build from within Jenkins, you'll be able to set any parameters you've configured.

Comment: You and I disagree about a robot proletariat ;)

Comment: You can take my release versioning from my cold dead hands!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom groovy script to automatically provide maven-release-plugin with the releaseVersion and developmentVersion. Then the maven command would look somwthing like:

mvn clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=${releaseVersion} -DdevelopmentVersion=${developmentVersion}

Follow the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557659/using-maven-release-plugin-autoversionsubmodules-to-increment-major-version/17699592#17699592) and change the part of the groovy script to suite your use-cases (for example this part):

```
def newFixVersion = 0;
if (hasSnapshotPart) {  
    newMinorRelVersion = minorVersion;  
    newMinorDevVersion = minorVersion + 1;  
} else {  
    //TODO: either throw an exception here or change the newMinorRelVersion newMinorDevVersion appropriately to suite your use-cases: 
        //throw new IllegalArgumentException("The pom at location " + POM_LOCATION + " contains the version " + projectVersion + " which is not a snapshot version (missing " + SNAPSHOT_PART + "). This is a released version and nothing should happen to it!");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I wanted to resolve it without running more than one command or by inserting the version manually.

Here is my solution for y (or minor) increment:

I run a Groovy script in **initialize** phase. This script creates **release.properties**. Add this to your **project/build/plugins** section in your **pom.xml**:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <!-- Force maven-release-plugin to increase MINOR, not PATCH, and create tag as vX.Y.Z -->
                <execution>
                    <id>release-parameters</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scripts>
                            <script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    final String SNAPSHOT = '-SNAPSHOT'

                                    Properties releaseProps = new Properties()
                                    File releasePropsFile = new File('release.properties')
                                    String releaseVersion = '${project.version}'.replace('-SNAPSHOT', '')
                                    String[] vNumbers = releaseVersion.split('\\.')
                                    String snapshotVersion = vNumbers[0] + '.' + (Integer.parseInt(vNumbers[1]) + 1) + '.' + '0' + SNAPSHOT

                                    releaseProps.setProperty('scm.tag', 'v' + releaseVersion)
                                    releaseProps.setProperty('project.rel.${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}', releaseVersion)
                                    releaseProps.setProperty('project.dev.${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}', snapshotVersion)
                                    releaseProps.store(releasePropsFile.newWriter(), null)
                                ]]>
                            </script>
                        </scripts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This script changes also the **tag** name for **vX.Y.Z** in your SCM. The **initialize** phase is not executed in the **release:prepare** phase. To resolve this issue, you can run a "mvn install" before a release, or change your release command to:

```
mvn --batch-mode initialize clean release:prepare release:perform
```

About release.properties: https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html

Answer (score 0):

Change VersionPolicy in `configuration` for `maven-release-plugin` in `pom.xml` – set parameter `projectVersionPolicyId` to **`SemVerVersionPolicy`** – it chooses „SemVer format and increase minor element when resolving the development version” instead of patch part (the default) – it increases the 2nd version part, instead of the 3rd version part.

See the `pom.xml` example fragment:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <projectVersionPolicyId>SemVerVersionPolicy</projectVersionPolicyId>
    […]
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Notes:

- `SemVerVersionPolicy` value for this parameter is available only in newer `maven-release-plugin` versions. I had problem using this Version Policy using `maven-release-plugin:2.5.3`, but it works OK for me after upgrade to version `3.0.0`.
- For older Plugin versions, as some other answers suggest, you could probably implement your own, custom Version Policy.

References:

- Plugin documentation page
  https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage/prepare-release.html#overriding-proposed-release-and-next-development-versions
- source JIRA issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-797
- source code on GitHub: https://github.com/apache/maven-release/tree/master/maven-release-policies/maven-release-semver-policy

Answer (score -1):

As suggested it Khmarbaise, I also think that **there is no solution to your problem.**

Is there any rule, that can automatically tell you if you must change the second or the third number ? Indeed, I don't think so. Saying that, you can't ask Maven / Jenkins to choose it for you, one time major version digit, the other minor version digit.

You must change it via a parameter, or let user configure it via the Jenkins M2 Release plugin, as suggested by willome. **It can only be a manual action.**