# Automatically bumping up pom.xml with Maven release plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I am playing with the Maven release plugin and I am trying to bump up the `pom.xml` version automatically. I noticed when I do:

```
mvn --batch-mode release:prepare
```

it will automatically bump up the `z` version, i.e. if it is `x.y.z` it will be `x.y.(z+1)`. Is there a way to bump up the `y` or `x` version without having to specify before hand what those versions should be?

Comment: I am surprised that no one even answered this after a year...

Comment: @user3626708, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon some blogposts on how to achieve this, and made this maven-setup which makes it possible to specify if you want to do a major, minor or patch-release:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.build.helper.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>parse-versions-for-release</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>parse-version</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyPrefix>parsedVersion</propertyPrefix>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>major</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>major</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                        <tagNameFormat>@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                        <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                        <releaseVersion>${parsedVersion.nextMajorVersion}.0.0</releaseVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>minor</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>minor</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                        <tagNameFormat>@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                        <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                        <releaseVersion>${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0</releaseVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Here we use the `build-helper-maven-plugin` to figure out what the current (and next) version is, and we use maven profiles to specify if we want to do a major, minor or patch (default) release.

Source code can be found here: https://github.com/mortenberg80/maven-release-example

The blog posts I got inspired from were:

- https://thihenos.medium.com/maven-release-plugin-a-simple-example-of-package-management-9926506acfb9
- [Maven release: next development version in batch mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15479851/)