# Maven Release: suggest next minor instead of patch/fix (1.X.0 instead of 1.0.X)

Tags: maven-release-plugin

I use the maven release plugin a lot. It works flawlessly so far, but one thing annoys me. Look at my latest release command I just fired (mvn release:prepare):

[image]

I worked on the current version 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT (built a few new features etc.) It's the "normal" release train, speaking I am not patching this version but rather bringing a new version on the road. My 1.4.0 shall now be finished and released.

After that I want to be working on version 1.5.0, the next release, as this is my new planned version. But the release plugin makes suggestions/autocomplete for patch level (third number, 1.4.1-SNAPSHOT in my case). I want it for minor level (second number, so that it suggests 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT).

If there are fixes to be done, I usually branch a tag, fix the bugs, and release a patch (1.4.1 for my case), and merge it back into my trunk, providing the 1.5.0 version the same bugfixes.
I am unsure if this is "the right way" or if there is even a really right way, but that's how we work in my company.

**So my question is: Is there a way to adjust the maven release settings so that it suggests minor updates rather than patch updates?**

As of today I need to type my desired versions by hand (no biggie, but I am curious if maven might be able to support me here).

PS: I found some SO questions but their answers didn't fit me well. Also they are a few years old, maybe now there are proper solutions without some groovy scripts or similar ...:

- [Using maven release plugin autoVersionSubmodules to increment Major version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557659/using-maven-release-plugin-autoversionsubmodules-to-increment-major-version)
- [Maven release: next development version in batch mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479851/maven-release-next-development-version-in-batch-mode)

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this? I cannot believe there is no popular/known standard for what seemingly looks like a common situation!

Comment: No, didn't search further so far. Always typing it from hand as I release like once a month or less - it's not a huge deal to bother about, but I still would prefer a possibility for configuration for this

Answer (score 2):

The [SemVerVersionPolicy](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-policies/maven-release-semver-policy/index.html) can be used to update the minor version.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <configuration>
        <projectVersionPolicyId>SemVerVersionPolicy</projectVersionPolicyId>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will propose the version 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT instead of 1.4.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: This solution seems to throw `NullPointerException` with older versions of the release plugin (because the policy is not found in the map of policies)?