# Maven Release Plugin auto increment custom format version

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, devops

I want to be able to auto-increment a java project's release version by using non-interactive mode in Maven release plugin (`mvn -B release:prepare`). However I do not want to use the default Maven versioning schema.

The schema that I would like to use is `<major>.<minor>.<bugfix>-SNAPSHOT`. I did manage to do this inside the pom file, however Maven tries to increment it as follows:

```
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
...
```

However I want to be able to have control on this and while some of the time I do have bugfixes and the above incrementing works, most of the times I would like to release minor releases and therefore an increment that looks like this:

```
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
...
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522234/maven-release-suggest-next-minor-instead-of-patch-fix-1-x-0-instead-of-1-0-x to increment minor version using standard semver policy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can handle this via [build-helper-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) like this:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
   release:prepare \
      -DdevelopmentVersion =\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT \
   release:perform
```

This will set the `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` as next development version..The next time you call release plugin it will make `1.1.0` from it and will automatically increment `1.1.1-SNAPSHOT` if you don't like just use the call above...

Comment: I get this error: `zsh: ${parsedVersion.majorVersion}..${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT not found`

Comment: how does the pom.xml should look like for this ? 

am getting this error mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${formattedVersion.minorVersion}.${formattedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT
-bash: -DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${formattedVersion.minorVersion}.${formattedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT: bad substitution

Answer (score 1):

"The maven way"is to follow maven rules, or to create a custom plugin. 
Maven plays nice as long as you want to do what it expects that you want to do.
Maybe solution for you would be to use just "1.1" most of the cases, and if you want to do a bugfix release, then to add 3rd number by hand.

However if you really wish to fight against maven, there is a possibility to setup properties from within some other plugin.. i.e. like this:

```
<profile>
  <id>customversionnumber</id>
  <build>
  <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>set-release-version</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>
                  project.properties.setProperty("releaseVersion","1.3.0")
                  System.out.println("releaseVersion set to 1.3.0")
              </source>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

Then, you'd invoke release plugin like this
`mvn -Pcustomversionnumber initialize release:prepare`. 
And it will release it as "1.3.0" regardless whats in 'version' tag. I'll have to code that number increment on your own of course.

Comment: scripting code inside a Maven pom not the best idea........better apply it from outside...this can not be controlled by CI solution likes Jenkins etc. or given by command line parameters...